# Theme CSS not updating on media/css_secure

Tags: magento-1.9, css, less-css

Recently my CSS files not updating to media/css_secure folder. I'm tried to kill cache but still its showing old CSS data. How to overcome to update my CSS. I am using Magento 1.9.2.2
[image: Modified File]

[image: Not Updating]

Comment: Hi Rajiv, can you confirm whether the hash stamp on the file is changing when you clear your cache?

Comment: No, It's not changing

Answer (score 2):

Many times css is cached by server.

1. Try renaming your css from layout xml and skin folder.
2. Make sure you are not using any CDN.
3. Try unmerging css.

Answer (score 1):

Rajiv,

If when you clear your cache the stamp on the CSS file stays the same, try turning merge CSS off in Sysytem > Configuration > Advanced > Developer. Clear the cache, then turn it back on to force Magento to recompile your CSS into a new merged file.

Hope this helps.

Josh

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not worked for me

Comment: Ok, so if you turn merge CSS off and then flush the cache and reload the page, do you see file paths in dev tools to the normal un-merged files, eg. `styles.css` ?